# Use src/ as the root of a Python package

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging

What configuration options should I use in setup.py:setup that would allow me to have the following package layout?

```
tests/
src/__init__.py
src/subpackage/__init__.py
```

I'm slightly embarrassed by not being able to figure this out.

I tried using

```
packages=find_namespace_packages("src")
package_dir={"": "src"}
```

and

```
packages=find_namespace_packages("src")
package_dir={"myrootpackage": "src"}
```

but neither seems to work.

Comment: If `src` should be a package (this is what it becomes if you put an `__init__.py` in the directory), then you need to provide neither of the options. What is the use of the `src` directory you strive for?

Comment: I want packages that depend on this package be able to use "import foo", but the actual code should not be under "src/foo" or "foo/", but under "src/__init__.py". Is that clearer?